# How is it possible get only the first related FAL image of a EXT:news record within EXT:solr?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

## Problem

After updating a TYPO3 website from TYPO3 4.5 to TYPO3 8.7 it was necessary to re-integrate EXT:solr's frontend (because of the Change to Fluid templating).

I have to display the first FAL related image `tx_news_domain_model.fal_media` of a news record which has showInPreview set to 1 or 2.

## My actual solution for `plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.news.fields.`...

does retrieve every image and limits to one. But this is not enough as I need `where=showinpreview=1`

```
image_stringS = TEXT
image_stringS {
    value = /typo3conf/ext/theme/Resources/Public/Images/solrImageDummy.gif
    override.cObject = FILES
    override.cObject {
        references {
            table = tx_news_domain_model_news
            uid.data = field:uid
            fieldName = fal_media
        }

        begin = 0
        maxItems = 1

        renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
        renderObj {
            file {
                import.dataWrap = {file:current:storage}:{file:current:identifier}
                width = 50c
                height = 50c
            }

            stdWrap.wrap = /|
        }
    }
}
```

### How is it possible to check also if the related image record has some specific properties?

Comment: i think this is a really bad design by EXT:news. In the project i'm currently working i completely deactivated all the "media" fields and added my own ones. Basically i have a field where you can store only one image which is used for previews and another field where you can add multiple additional images. With this kind of approach, i don't have do make strange decisions in my code and i think it could also benefit your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care to change the order of the files you could use `sorting` to get the files you are interested in in the beginning.

Otherwise you need to omit `maxItems` and maybe limit the files in your fluid.
Then you can filter in the `renderObj` by some easy `.stdWrap.if` which files should be in the array given to fluid.

As you have no fluid (you want to give it to solr), you might use a trick:
if you have an array, you could render all relevant information into one string, but you need a unique separator (could be `stdWrap.wrap = /|##!!##`)
then you split it afterwards to use only the first entry.

```
override.cObject {
    :
    stdWrap.split {
        token = ##!!##
        ## we need only the first, but does indexing start with 0 or 1?
        ## and will 0 be recognized?
        returnKey = 0
    }
}
```

maybe you need this:

```
override.cObject {
    stdWrap.split {
        :
        cObjNum {
            # render first entry
            1 = TEXT
            1.current = 1

            # ignore all further entries
        }
    }
}
```